# JBenchX eclipse very slow

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a JBenchX method that calculates a keys of CMSS signature using flexiprovider. I want to get timings for my method createKeys, but that is very very slow. Without annnotation @Bench that is too fast < 1 sec. Could you help to understand What's happen here?

```
import de.flexiprovider.api.exceptions.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyPair;
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyPairGenerator;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.Bench;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.ForEachInt;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.ForEachString;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.SingleRun;

public class CMSSTest {

@Bench
public Object createKeys(@ForEachString({ "CMSSwithSHA1andWinternitzOTS_1" }) String cmss) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiPQCProvider());

        //byte[] signatureBytes = null;
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = (CMSSKeyPairGenerator) Registry
                .getKeyPairGenerator(cmss);
        KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
}
}
```

The actual output is and is active yet.

Initializing Benchmarking Framework...
Running on Linux Linux
Max heap = 1345847296 System Benchmark = 11,8ns
Performing 1 benchmarking tasks..
[0] CMSSTest.createObjectArray(CMSSwithSHA1andWinternitzOTS_1)!*!**!!!******!!******!****!****!!******!!!!*******!******!****!*********************************

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `Registry.getKeyPairGenerator` creates a new KeyPairGenerator which is initialized using a 'true' random seed. For this, the system potentially has to wait for enough entropy to be available. Therefore, you should not do this as part of the code that you want to benchmark.

Try something like this:

```
import java.security.Security;

import org.jbenchx.annotations.Bench;
import org.jbenchx.annotations.ForEachString;

import de.flexiprovider.api.Registry;
import de.flexiprovider.api.exceptions.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyPair;
import de.flexiprovider.api.keys.KeyPairGenerator;
import de.flexiprovider.pqc.FlexiPQCProvider;

public class CMSSTest {

  static {
    Security.addProvider(new FlexiPQCProvider());
  }

  private final KeyPairGenerator kpg;

  public CMSSTest(@ForEachString({"CMSSwithSHA1andWinternitzOTS_1"}) String cmss) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    this.kpg = Registry.getKeyPairGenerator(cmss);
  }

  @Bench
  public Object createKeys() {
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
    return keyPair;
  }
}
```